# In Nodesjs using Express how do I regexp my url?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

Ive been using an online regexp tool to check my regexp expression. On the sight I can get my regexp to check out, but in node it will fail.

What I am trying to catch is this pattern:

```
/XX/something/somethingelse/whatisleft
```

My regexp is :

```
/^([A-Z]{2}\/something\/somethingelse\/.*)$
```

Comment: If you are checking with regexp your url for routing purposes it is a very bad idea. If you want to specify some default behavior for the url's you did not specify a route for you should add at the end of your route definition `app.get('*', ...)` or handle it in an error handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the leading `/` in the regex and the trailing slash to end the regex.  It should be:

```
/^\/([A-Z]{2}\/something\/somethingelse\/.*)$/
```

Comment: I copied yours and missed the trailing slash as well

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you provide the actual routing line you have? `app.get(/^\/([A-Z]{2}\/something\/somethingelse\/.*)$/, function(req, res, next) `

Comment: That didn't work either here is the route: `app.get('/^\/([A-Z]{2}\/something\/somethingelse\/.*)$/', routes.handleIt(tryCount));`

Comment: Your trying to use a string match, not a regex.  Lose the ' and it should work.  `app.get(/regex/, cb)`

Comment: It's always the small things that hang you up the longest. Thanks for your help jeremy that did the job.